"Не найден контекст данных для привязки" MAUI
Необходимо привязать свойство, но он его не видит (Не найден контекст данных для привязки "CanChoice").
XAML:
<Button Clicked="ChoiceFeelings" Text="Кнопка" IsEnabled="{Binding CanChoice}"/>
Свойство:
public bool CanChoice
{
    get => canChoice;
    set
    {
        canChoice = value;
        OnPropertyChanged(nameof(CanChoice));
    }
}

bool canChoice = true;


Для привязки должно быть соблюдено 3 вещи: 1. Должен быть установлен BindingContext на тот класс, где хранятся все свойства для привязок. 2. В этом классе должно быть свойство как минимум с get-тером. 3 Свойство должно быть публичным. Об этом всем довольно подробно сказано в документации. Ну вот теперь и изучайте свой код и смотрите, что у вас не так. Также изучайте лог ошибок. Если вы уверены, что все верно, то очистите и пересоберите проект, ибо XAML обновляется только после успешной сборки.
